# Bluetooth peripheral disconnect when a phone call is in progress

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I configured my app to support backgroud bluetooth-central mode, the app connects to the pereferal and subscribe to one of its characteristic's value.

The app works fine on background mode, but once I receive or made a phone call, the peripheral disconnect, but the app still always on background.

I'm not performing any Long-Term Actions in the Background, but I'm managing to start the scan once the peripheral disconnect.

I think maybe the phone call signal is more powerful than the bluetooth one, so it  disturbs it!!

Does anyone know the real reason of the problem? Any suggestions!